# bash background operator & error with AND operator &&

Tags: bash

If I try to execute this code in bash shell will work fine:

```
date && echo "hello world"
```

But if I want to run date in background and then use echo it does not work:

```
date & && echo "hello world"
```

Edit:

The final task is run a script that connect to vpn:

```
# openvpn /etc/openvpn/client/my_vpn.ovpn
```

And if this work that appear a message. The problem is that vpn command is always running and the next command not show. Ej:

```
# openvpn /etc/openvpn/client/my_vpn.ovpn  && notify-send "VPN connect"
```

I tried:

```
# openvpn /etc/openvpn/client/my_vpn.ovpn  & && notify-send "VPN connect"
```

The second message never run, so I tried run a more simple command for test with date.

Comment: This does not make sense. The && means "execute the next command, if the previous one had exit code 0", but you put the previous program in the background which means "execute it at some time". You don't have an exit code yet. You could do a `wait` for the background program, but then it is meaningless to place it in the background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because just like semicolon and line break characters, ampersand is a command separator too.

```
date ; && echo 'hello world'
```

and

```
date
&& echo 'hello world'
```

won't work either.

If you did

```
{ date & } && echo 'hello word'
```

however, it'd work. But that doesn't make any sense, asynchronous commands (e.g. `date &`) always return zero.

Answer (score 1):

If you run a command in the background, what would be the meaning of `&&`? You don't wait for the command to finish, so you don't know whether it was successful or not. Just use the `&` operator alone to separate the commands:

```
date & echo 'hello world'
```

Answer (score 1):

Need more information about your task.
Because the exact answer depends on the conditions that you did not say.

**For example:**
If your task is to run a code in the background and, if it succeeds, print a message to standard output, then this is done like this:

```sh
{ date && echo "hello world"; } &
```

**Or**
If you have a task, run something in the background and later get the result, then this is done like this:

```sh
coproc dateDoneUndone { 
    date && {echo "Done"; } || {echo "UnDone"; } 
}

# some code

readarray -u ${dateDoneUndone[0]} ans; 
echo "Result: ${ans[@]}"
```

In order to better understand what this code does, you need to read documentation about [redirections](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html#Redirections), [job control](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Job-Control.html#Job-Control) and [coprocesses](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Coprocesses.html#Coprocesses).

Comment: The task is run a script that connect to vpn:

# openvpn /etc/openvpn/client/mivpn.ovpn 

And if this work that appear a message. The problem is that vpn command is always running and the next command not show. Ej:

openvpn /etc/openvpn/client/mivpn.ovpn && notify-send "VPN connect"

I tried:

openvpn /etc/openvpn/client/mivpn.ovpn & && notify-send "VPN connect"

The second message never run, I tried run a more simple command for test with date.